# Rejecting in suggested edit queue, if you click on, causes harm, and the other option still highlights

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I am rejecting an edit on the suggested edit queue. I first clicked on "attempt to reply", and then, clicked on "causes harm". But, "attempt to reply" is still highlighted even though the radio button is on "causes harm". The "causes harm" option should be highlighted.

[image]

This appears when first clicking on other options as well.

To reproduce:

1. first, go to a suggested edit queue. (>2k or if you are the owner of the post)
2. second, click on <kbd>Reject</kbd>
3. click on any option except causes harm.
4. click inside the "causes harm" textbox.

Also reproducible on mobile version this way too.

Comment: Also repro'd on mobile version.

Comment: Has this bug been fixed yet?

Comment: Now this is fixed.